# OpenCV 3.1.0 Assertion failed checkDetectorSize in cv::HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to train SVM with my own images and feed that to the HOGDescriptor in OpenCV.
The training looks to be going well, but when I try to give the model to the HOGDescriptor with the `setSVMDetector` function it fails.
Code for training

```
    Mat trainingImages = new Mat();
    Mat trainingLables = new Mat();

    String personsPath = "C:\INRIAPerson\\INRIAPerson\\96X160H96\\Train\\pos";

    for (File file : new File(personsPath).listFiles()) {
        if(file.isFile()){
            Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(file.getPath());
            Mat newImg = new Mat();
            Imgproc.cvtColor(img, newImg, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
            newImg = newImg.reshape(1,1);

            trainingImages.push_back(newImg);
            trainingLables.push_back(Mat.ones(new Size(1,1), CvType.CV_32SC1));
        }
    }


    String nonPersonsPath = "C:\\NRIAPerson\\INRIAPerson\\train_64x128_H96\\neg";
    for (File file : new File(nonPersonsPath).listFiles()) {
        if(file.isFile()){
            Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(file.getPath());
            Mat newImg = new Mat();
            Imgproc.cvtColor(img, newImg, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

            Imgproc.resize(newImg, newImg, new Size(160 , 96));
            newImg = newImg.reshape(1,1);

            trainingImages.push_back(newImg);
            trainingLables.push_back(Mat.zeros(new Size(1,1), CvType.CV_32SC1));
        }
    }

    trainingImages.convertTo(trainingImages, CvType.CV_32FC1);

    SVM trainer = SVM.create();
    trainer.setKernel(SVM.LINEAR);
    trainer.train(trainingImages, Ml.ROW_SAMPLE, trainingLables);

    HOGDescriptor hog = new HOGDescriptor(new Size(160, 96), new Size(8,8), new Size(4,4), new Size(4,4), 9);
    Mat supportVector = trainer.getSupportVectors();
    hog.setSVMDetector(supportVector);
```

The error message

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (checkDetectorSize()) in cv::HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector, file C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\hog.cpp, line 117
Exception in thread "main" CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: C:\builds\master_PackSlaveAddon-win64-vc12-static\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\hog.cpp:117: error: (-215) checkDetectorSize() in function cv::HOGDescriptor::setSVMDetector
]
    at org.opencv.objdetect.HOGDescriptor.setSVMDetector_0(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.objdetect.HOGDescriptor.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor.java:302)
    at feature.extraction.App.main(App.java:86)
```

I don't know if the libpng warning's have anything to do with it.
It's driving me crazy does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I was doing a couple thing wrong

1. I was training with images and not `features`
2. I forgot adding `-rho` to the supportvector

First I created a `2d float array`. Populated it with the features of the image by using the `compute` function from the `HOGDescriptor` class. Trained the SVM with the array. After the training I used the `getDecisionFunction` function to get the `rho` and appended that to the `supportvector`.